# allowNull:false and required:true did not validate null string input

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My app is running nodejs 10.16 and sequelizejs 5.7 with postgresql 11. The initial connection is setup as:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('mydb', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:5432,       
} );
```

A `Group` model is defined as:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const Sql = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../startup/db");

const Group = db.define('group', {
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
           allowNull: false,
           min: 1,
           max: 50,
           required: true,
    },
    owner_id: {
      type: Sql.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      required: true,
    },   
    status: {type: Sql.STRING,
             allowNull: false,
             isIn: ['active', 'inactive']
    },
    last_updated_by_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER},
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
  }, {
    indexes: [
      { 
        fields: ['name', 'owner_id']
      }
    ]   

  });

function validateGroup(group) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string()
        .min(1)
        .max(50)
        .required()
        .trim(),
    status: Joi.string()
        .required()
        .trim(),
    });

    return schema.validate(group,  {allowUnknown: true});
};

module.exports.Group = Group;
module.exports.validateGroup = validateGroup;
```

Here is the in router `/group/new` to save a new group:

```
router.post('/new',  async (req, res) => {
    const { err } = validateGroup(req.body);
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err.details[0].message);

    let group = Group.build(_.pick(req.body, ['name', 'status']));
    group.owner_id = req.user.id;
    group.last_updated_by_id = req.user.id;
    let grpmember = new Groupmember({owner_id: req.user.id});
    try {
        await db.transaction(async () => {
            await group.save();
            grpmember.group_id = group.id;
            await grpmember.save();

            return res.status(200).send(`${group.name}-已经保存！`);
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error in saving new group ", err);
        return res.status(400).send('保存错误，请再试一遍！');
    };

});
```

Here is the `Group` table output which contains both empty and non-empty name:

[image]

Why the validation for `name` field, such as `allowNull:false` and `required: true` did not validate the input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the code that works:

```
const Group = db.define('group', {
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
          validate: {
            len:{
              args:[1,50],
              msg:"Name between 1 to 50 chars"
            } ,
          }
    },
    owner_id: {
      type: Sql.INTEGER,
      validate: {
        isInt: true,
      },
    },   
    status: {type: Sql.STRING,
             validate: {
              isIn: ['active', 'inactive'],
             },

    },
    group_data: {
        type: Sql.JSONB
    },
    last_updated_by_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER},
    fort_token: {type: Sql.STRING,
                 validate: {
                   min:20, //64 for production
                 },
    },
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
  }
```